# Cannot do operator << overloading

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I just started learning CPP and I'm having troubles with operator overloading.
I want to overload the "<<" operator from the ostream lib.
This is my declaration in the header file :

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out ,const Stone s);
```

and that is the cpp file:

```
ostream& Stone:: operator<<( ostream &out , const Stone s ){
```

The given error is :
    1   IntelliSense: class "Stone" has no member "operator<<"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't post pictures of code, use copy-paste of the actual code instead.

Comment: You defined a member function, omit the `Stone::` at the function definition.

Comment: As for your problem, declaring a friend function inside a class doesn't make the function a *member* function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your cpp file

```
std::ostream& Stone::operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Stone s)
              ^^^^^
{
}
```

It's not a member function and should be:

```
// Also note the 2nd argument is `const &` (i.e., don't copy the object if you don't have to
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Stone& foo)
{

}
```

### Full Example

If you're still having problems you should post more code and/or your errors. The following works for me.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : mValue(99) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Foo& foo);

private:
    int mValue;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Foo& foo)
{
    return stream << foo.mValue;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    std::cout << f << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but now the problem is that the members in the stone class are inaccessible although  the func is a friend func

Comment: @Itay209 I updated my answer with a full example but it should be working for you. As you can see the friend function is accessing a private data member.

Answer (score 0):

In the header file, the friend declaration needs to be within the definition of class `Stone`.

In the source (you call it "cpp") file, the header file needs to be included before trying to define/implement the `operator<<()`.

A friend is not a member, so should not be preceded by `Stone::`.

A couple of other niceties.

- Never use `using namespace std` in a header file because it can cause
  ambiguity which is quite difficult to recover from.   Name `ostream`
  in full (i.e. as `std::ostream`).
- The second argument of `operator<<()` is usually best as a
  `const` reference, not passing by value.